# jQuery datatable - Object doesn't support property or method 'numeric-DESC'

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery datatable, and keep getting the error with message "Object doesn't support property or method 'numeric-DESC'"

The following are my codes:

```
    var oTable = $('#tbSns').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bStateSave": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "aaSorting": [[1,'DESC']]
    });
```

Guess something wrong with aaSorting, however, still tring to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but I'd say that `"DESC"` is case sensitive, and should be `"desc"`.

From the [plugin's website](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html):

> *"The aaSorting parameter is an array of arrays where the first value is the column to sort on, and the second is 'asc' or 'desc' as required (it is a double array for multi-column sorting)."*

So:

```
var oTable = $('#tbSns').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bStateSave": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
    "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']]  // <-- lowercase 'desc'
});
```